# MessageAppExtension: how to load sticker images from assets to MSStickerBrowserView?

Tags: ios, swift, message, swift3, ios10

Alright, I know this is new for everybody but I would think it'd be a simple concept - I am following this here to make a custom sticker message app extension:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-imessage-app-in-ios-10--cms-26870

Ive copied everything exactly and am trying to create a basic MSStickerBrowserView displaying (then later filtering using logic, but haven't attempted that yet) sticker pngs I have in my assets folder here:

[image]

The tutorial did not load from assets it seems but rather just from their project, regardless their code is old as here:

```
var stickers = [MSSticker]()

    func loadStickers() {
        for i in 1...2 {
            if let url = Bundle.main.urlForResource("Sticker \(i)",  withExtension: "png") { //ERROR!!
                do {
                    let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "")
                    stickers.append(sticker)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error

> Bundle has no member URLforResource

I can't find anything on this. How can I just display my stickers programmatically in the app?

Error:

[image]

These are the images Im trying to load regardless of their name:

[image]

Comment: Ok but look at my question for the error - how can I load in the contents of my assets folder with this?

Comment: Sorry, new to this

Comment: In Swift 3 it should be Bundle.main.url(forResource: String?, withExtension: String?)

Comment: Sorry, I provided the wrong statement. Check it now.

Comment: Ok, that works but how do I just load ALL the pngs I have in my sticker pack folder in assets? I included an image above

Comment: I should work with code you wrote. System gets each image url and creates a MSSticker.

Comment: Thank you yes it does but I just want to get ALL the stickers in my assets folder regardless of name

Answer (score 5):

The reason that tutorial doesn't use asset catalogs is that you cannot get a valid fileURL for images placed in an .xcassets folder when calling the urlForResource method on the bundle.

You need to add your assets individually like you would other files you are bringing in to the app. Calling pathForResource or urlForResource on the bundle at that point will no longer return nil.

EDIT: Here is a function that will take a folder name, loop through it's contents and return [MSSticker]? based on what it finds

```
func createStickers(from folderName: String) -> [MSSticker]? {

    guard
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath
        else { return nil }

    var stickers = [MSSticker]()
    let folderPath = "\(path)/\(folderName)"
    let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderPath)

    //get a list of urls in the chosen directory
    do {
        let imageURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL,
                                                                    includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
                                                                    options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        //loop through the found urls
        for url in imageURLs {
            //create the sticker and add it, or handle error
            do {
                let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "yourDescription")
                stickers.append(sticker)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    //return nil if stickers array is empty
    return stickers.isEmpty ? nil : stickers
}
```

This should let you just call this and get what you are after:

```
let stickers = createStickers(from: "YourFolderName")
```

Please note not to include the forward slash ('/') at the beginning of the folder name.

Comment: Yes I figured that out, but I want to bring in a folder full of specific images and iterate through them (not just individual images). I cant bring in a folder so far because folders don't have any extensions so you cant use urlForResource - how can I do this?

Comment: @skyguy - I added a function that accomplishes what you are after. I have tested it in a sample project and was able to iterate through the folder and create the stickers with the images only added to the extension.

Comment: Not getting it to work... where should the folder be exactly?

Comment: I put it in the extension folder, and everything works as expected

Comment: I tried this and had an error: The file “stickerpack” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. However, there definitely IS a folder inside my extension called "stickerpack" that contains the images. It was set with the target of the extension when added. When I print the folderURL it looks correct too.

Comment: It is from the outer  "do/catch" on the function.

Comment: is it an .xcassets folder?

Comment: Just a regular subfolder. I dragged it into the project (under my extension folder) from the finder.

Comment: Just ran mine again...works fine but I get the same error message when trying to access a folder that isn't there or is an asset folder. I would recommend looking in the simulator directory and following the path to verify that it is, in fact, there

Comment: Figured it out... I needed to tick "create folder reference" in the options when dragging the folder onto the project.

Comment: @skyguy just specify nil for extension and it will get your folder

Answer (score 1):

Just replace "resourceUrl" with:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sticker \(i)", withExtension: "png")
```

The code got replaced in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in a folder like so (XCODE Viewport):

[image]

It make things more organised but doesnt need as much code as if you would put them in a .xcasset.

It can be put done by creating a new group instead of creating an .xcasset by (Right Clicking Message Extension and clicking New Group):

[image]

The following code for the StickerBrowserView can be called like so:

```swift
import UIKit
import Messages

class StickerBrowserViewController: MSStickerBrowserViewController {

  var stickers = [MSSticker]()

  func changeBrowserViewBackgroundColor(color: UIColor){
    stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = color
  }

  func loadStickers(){

    createSticker(asset: "1", localizedDescription:"grinning face")
    createSticker(asset: "2", localizedDescription:"grimacing face")
    createSticker(asset: "3", localizedDescription:"grinning face with smiling eyes")
    createSticker(asset: "4", localizedDescription:"face with tears of joy")
    createSticker(asset: "5", localizedDescription:"smiling face with open mouth")
    createSticker(asset: "6", localizedDescription:"smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes")

  }

  func createSticker(asset: String, localizedDescription: String){

    guard let stickerPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:asset, ofType:"png") else {
      print("couldn't create the sticker path for", asset)
      return
    }

    // we use URL so, it's possible to use image from network
    let stickerURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:stickerPath)

    let sticker: MSSticker
    do {

      try sticker = MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: stickerURL, localizedDescription: localizedDescription)
      // localizedDescription for accessibility

      stickers.append(sticker)
    }catch {
      print(error)
      return
    }

  }

  override func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int{
    return stickers.count
  }

  override func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker{

    return stickers[index] as MSSticker

  }

}
```

(Ps. Not my blog, but found it on google and it has been very useful)